# Warning installing ionic 2

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, cmd, npm, ionic2

I´m trying to install ionic 2 in my windows 10 64 bits.

My npm version is 3.10.9

When I tried to install with this line:

```
npm install -g --save ionic cordova
```

The CMD says:

[image: a warning]

A lot of people thinks I can still working, but, the fact is: not found command ionic, so I don´t know what to do.

Comment: Do you know where global modules are installed? What is `npm config get prefix`? Is that on your PATH?

Comment: type ionic-g to check your ionic is installed.

Comment: Well the warnings are nothing to worry about at least. Try running them isolated `npm install ionic -g` and then `npm install cordova -g` and check afterwards. If this doesn't work it's possible that your `npm` is installing the global packages in another directory then where your path is configured

Comment: why are you using the `--save` flag? just `npm install -g ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to restart the computer. Then the computer recognize the enviroment variable.